# Explain like I'm 5: How does MoneroDice work?

Tags: monerodice

I've read how it is provably fair. I've also read that it "rolls" a number in the range: `(0 <= X <= 99.99)`.

Please explain how the multiplier, return on win, and over/under are calculated to give a person an understanding of what one is doing when placing a bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**return on win** = (*bet amount*)(*multiplier*)

**chance of winning** = 99/*multiplier*

(If one rolls more than the chance of winning)
**over** = (100 - *chance of winning*)
(If one rolls less than the chance of winning)
**under** = (100 - *over*)

Comment: How is that "provably fair"?

Comment: I wasn't concerned about answering the provably fair part. That is answered here: https://monerodice.net/index.php/member/fair